# app restarts after exiting the app using system.exit

Tags: java, android

I created in my application an option that if the user clicks on the onBackPress that it will pop up a dialog asking if they are sure they want to exit the app.

Once they click ok, I had like it to close the app and thats it.

However, right now it closes the app but then restarts it and returns again to the same screen.

Im using:

```
public void popExitDialog(Context context) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog( context );
    dialog.setContentView( R.layout.item_warn_exit );
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT ) );

    Button Btn_Continue = dialog.findViewById( R.id.btn_Continue );
    Button Btn_Cancel = dialog.findViewById( R.id.btn_Cancel );
    ImageButton ib_CloseDialog = dialog.findViewById( R.id.ib_CloseDialog );

    dialog.show();

    ib_CloseDialog.setOnClickListener( v -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } );

    Btn_Cancel.setOnClickListener( view -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } );

    Btn_Continue.setOnClickListener( view -> {
        AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = new AppCompatActivity();
        appCompatActivity.finishAndRemoveTask();
        appCompatActivity.finishAffinity();
        System.exit( 1 );
    } );
}
```

How can I stop this auto startup?

Thank you

Comment: Did you change System.exit( 1 ); to System.exit( 0 ); like in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You try my code, I also used dialog box for exiting my app and it's work fine for me. Hope it will do same for you

```
((Activity) context).finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `finishAffinity()` from your main activity!

The `AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = new AppCompatActivity();` in your code is not related to any of your activitys. You're basically just creating a new, empty activity object, that is not referenced in your application.

If you call `finishAffinity()` from your main activity, than this also closes all other activitys, that are below it in the [Task Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html). So you NEED to call `finishAffinity()` from your
MAIN (first activity running when starting the application)-`(Activity) context`
Then you can try:

```
Btn_Continue.setOnClickListener( view -> {
    (Activity)your_context.finishAffinity();
    System.exit(0);
} );
```

Note that this code is working on Android 10. I just tested it out.

Comment: My exiting code appear in an interface where I use it in many different activies. when I try to use context.finishAffinity I get an error saying cannot resolve. I added a fuller code.

Comment: I edited my answer. How are you running this code from an interface ? Please post the full interface and where you are implementing it

Answer (score 0):

try System.exit(0)

exit(0) : Generally used to indicate successful termination.
exit(1) or exit(-1) or any other non-zero value – Generally indicates unsuccessful termination.

Try this : Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

Comment: Tried it also, the same result.

Comment: try this : Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());